# Powershell array sum on column based on another

Tags: powershell

I've got a custom object retrieved from a SQL Query which looks like this

This is basically how I've constructed the object and it works fine but I can't seem to find how to group them.

```
foreach ($row in $result) {
$props = @{ 'MailboxName' = $row.MailboxName
            'PSTsFound' = $row.PSTsFound
            'Messagesremaining' = $row.Messagesremaining
          }
          $obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $props
          $userPSTs += $obj
}
```

Column1    Column2

User1      3
User1      6
User1      8
User2      10
User2      3
User3      4
User4      6
User4      2

And I want to turn it into this

Column1   Column2
User1     17
User2     13
User3     4
User4     8

So basically sum the column2 where column1 matches.

Thanks in advance for any assistance

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you by `Column1` and `Column2` mean `MailboxName` and `PSTsFound`

If you are just interested in the sum of PSTsFound for all rows with the same MailboxName, and not the individual rows, you could use a HashTable with the MailboxName as the key and the entire object as your value. Then in your iteration, test whether your HashTable already contains a given key - if so, add the value to the existing entry:

```
$SumTable = @{}

foreach ($row in $result) {
    if($SumTable.ContainsKey($row.MailboxName))
    {
        $obj = $SumTable[$row.MailboxName]
        $obj.PSTsFound += $row.PSTsFound
        $obj.Messagesremaining += $row.Messagesremaining
        $SumTable[$row.MailboxName] = $obj
    }
    else
    {
        $props = @{
            'MailboxName' = $row.MailboxName
            'PSTsFound' = $row.PSTsFound
            'Messagesremaining' = $row.Messagesremaining
        }
        $obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $props
        $SumTable.Add($obj.MailboxName,$obj)
    }
}

$userPSTs = $SumTable.Values
```

---

If you don't want to modify the existing collection, but just want to output the sum, you can utilize the [Group-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849907(v=wps.620).aspx) and [Measure-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849965(v=wps.620).aspx) cmdlets in [this brilliant approach suggested on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6000217/712649):

```
$userPSTs | Group-Object -Property MailboxName | Foreach-Object {
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        MailboxName = $_.MailboxName
        PSTsFound = ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property PSTsFound -Sum).Sum
        Messagesremaining = ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property Messagesremaining -Sum).Sum
    }
}
```